# Use lookup table in foreach with list

Tags: python

I'm trying to use my lookup table along with a list to determine if and how many times I should run a function.

If I have a lookup table like

```
bar = {
         "one": 1
         "two": 2
       "three": 3
}

lis = [1, 4, 5, 3]
```

So with this such a setup I'd like to check if `lis` contains any of the keys in `bar`, and for each occurence do something like:

```
for(lis in bar):
    //something
```

Comment: yes, and doing something for each occurence

Comment: lis seems to contain *values* in `bar`. `for lis in bar` gives you `"one" "two" "three"`. Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: The keys and values in `bar` seem to be swapped, given the intended operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would do something like:

```
lis = [1,4,5,3]
values = bar.values()
for i in lis:
    if i in values:
        #do stuff
```

Comment: Excellent, simple I like it!

Comment: `keys` is unnecessary, `if i in bar:` would work perfectly fine.

Comment: I included the keys just to show that you are allowed to get that list if necessary, but yes.

Comment: As the OP code stands, the keys of `bar` are `"one" "two" "three"`, whereas the numbers lie in the values. See the comments above

Comment: Gah, posting late at night makes me mix things up, I meant values. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do but it is ugly:

```
for x in (a for a in lis if a in bar):
    # Something
```

But I wouldn't recommend it and would favour:

```
for x in lis:
    if x not in bar:
        continue
    # Something
```

If the do something is a function that you care about the results you can do:

```
results = [do_something(x) for x in lis if x in bar]
```